# How do you reverse fill a Progress Bar with javascript?

Tags: javascript

This code is from w3schools, but I'm trying to figure out how do I reverse the bar from 100% to zero when another button is clicked?

https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_js_progressbar_label_js

Thank you!

Comment: Welcome to SO. You might find reading the site [help section](https://stackoverflow.com/help) useful when it comes to [asking a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). To get the best answers to your question we like to see that you've attempted to solve the problem yourself first using a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Here's a [question checklist](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist) you might find useful...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work, just create another function and init the `width` variable at 100 and then decrease it (`width--`) instead of increase it:

```js
var i = 0;
function move() {
  if (i == 0) {
    i = 1;
    var elem = document.getElementById("myBar");
    var width = 10;
    var id = setInterval(frame, 10);
    function frame() {
      if (width >= 100) {
        clearInterval(id);
        i = 0;
      } else {
        width++;
        elem.style.width = width + "%";
        elem.innerHTML = width  + "%";
      }
    }
  }
}

function reverse() {
  if (i == 0) {
    i = 1;
    var elem = document.getElementById("myBar");
    var width = 100;
    var id = setInterval(frame, 10);
    function frame() {
      if (width <= 0) {
        clearInterval(id);
        i = 0;
      } else {
        width--;
        elem.style.width = width + "%";
        elem.innerHTML = width  + "%";
      }
    }
  }
}
```

```css
#myProgress {
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #ddd;
}

#myBar {
  width: 10%;
  height: 30px;
  background-color: #04AA6D;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 30px;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<h1>JavaScript Progress Bar</h1>

<div id="myProgress">
  <div id="myBar">10%</div>
</div>

<br>
<button onclick="move()">Click Me</button> 
<button onclick="reverse()">Reverse it</button>
```

Comment: If this answers helps, you could click the check mark next to it to mark it correct.